# Use pdb debugger in a pythonanywhere free account

Tags: python, flask, pdb, pythonanywhere

How can I break into the `pdb` Python debugger in a Flask app when using a pythonanywhere free account?
I want to use: `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` and step through the code following this statement.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't, I'm afraid.  The servers that run your web app are separate from the ones that run consoles, so you wouldn't be able to get an interactive shell connected to a live web worker running your app.

Your best bet is probably to try and write some kind of automated test for the part of your flask app that you're trying to debug -- I'm not sure what flask's test harnesses are like, but there must be a way of writing unit tests for it?  Then you could run the test in a console, and break out into a pdb session within that...

[edit to add link]

There are some [docs on how to do testing in flask here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/testing/). If you set up a test runner like that, then use `self.app.get('/url-you-want-to-debug')`, then you should be able to break out into a pdb session for that url.  and it might have the neat side-effect that you'll start building up a test suite for your app, which is always a good thing...